# Setting up Home Server

Tags: apache

I'm trying to setup my home server. The Server is using Ubuntu 13.10 and Apache 2.4.6.
What I have done:

- I have registered the domain name
- Added domain to freeDNS
- setup ddclient as daemon
- freeDNS status is active
- port 80 forwarded on router
- In sites-available cp 000-default.conf deadpickle.conf

  ```
  <VirtualHost deadpickle.com:80>
  ServerName deadpickle.com
  ServerAlias www.deadpickle.com
  ServerAdmin deadpickle@deadpickle.com
  DocumentRoot /var/www
  ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
  CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
  </VirtualHost>
  ```
- sudo a2ensite deadpickle.conf

Light tests looking for the It Works from apache:

- localhost works
- 192.168.2.2:80 on another computer on the same router works
- deadpickle.com NOT WORKING
- www.deadpickle.com NOT WORKING

What do I need to do to type deadpickle.com into my browser and have it show the "It Works" text from apache?

Comment: Do you have a router inbetween? Is it forwarding 80 traffic to your machine?

Comment: I forgot to mention that, yes it is

Comment: I can access both 'www.deadpickle.com' and 'deadpickle.com' .try using google DNS on your PC.looks like your domain is new.it could take up to 24 hours to propagate a new domain across DNS servers.

Comment: What do you mean by accessing them? I would love to use google dns but I dont understand how to set it up with a godaddy registar.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I am foolish. I was trying to access deadpickle.com on my LAN. When I used my phone off network I got the It works text.